How to align O-TM-O along z axis of unit cell of P2 like structure
I was surveying this article https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-018-0117-4, here the P2 like layered oxide structure where he O-TM-O bonds are not aligned along the z-axis. As a result, VASP provides a mixture of $e_g$ and $t_{2g}$ (As we know, the VASP default output for partial DOS considers the z-axis of the xyz coordinate for projection). To project accurately to obtain $e_g$ and $t_{2g}$ I want to rotate the structure with respect to the global coordinate (xyz) to align Oxygen-TransitionMetal-Oxygen (O-TM-O) bond along the z axis, to achieve this I need an accurate python code where I need to multiply atomic coordinates and basis with a rotation matrix(namely modify the matrix of the lattice parameters in POSCAR accordingly), The value of a,b,c,alpha,beta,gamma(lattice parameters) must not change.
